# Concatenated string list code from dplyr to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to convert the following code from dplyr mode to data.table

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
Text = c("A little bird told me about the dog", "A pig in a poke", "As busy as a bee")
data = as.data.frame(Text)
keywords <- paste0(c("bird", "dog", "pig","wolf","cat", "bee", "turtle"), collapse = "|")
data %>% 
  mutate(Words = str_extract_all(Text, keywords),
         Words = map(Words, ~ as.list(unique(.x)) %>% 
                       set_names(str_c('col', seq_along(.))))) %>%
  unnest_longer(Words) %>% 
  group_by(Text) %>% 
  arrange(Words) %>% 
  summarise(result = paste(Words, collapse = " + "))
```

What I start trying is

```
DT = setDT(data)
DT[, Words = str_extract_all(Text, keywords)]
DT[, Words = map(Words ~ as.list(unique(.x))]
DT[, Words = unlist(Words), by = Text]
```

but it gives an error `RHS is NULL when grouping :=. Makes no sense to delete a column by group. Perhaps use an empty vector instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, after extracting all the words, use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, get  the `unique` and `paste`, and `unlist` to a `vector` before doing the assignment (`:=`)

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(data)[,  Words := unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(Text, keywords), 
         function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse= " + ")))]
```

NOTE: the assignment operator is `:=` and not a `=`, if we use `=`, it can be inside a `list` or `.(`

---

With `tidyverse`, the `unnest` and then `group_by` can be removed

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   mutate(Words = map_chr(str_extract_all(Text, keywords), ~
        unique(.x) %>%
           sort %>% 
           str_c(collapse = " + ")))
```

Comment: Very interesting and to do the list in alphabetical order I can just use `sort(unique(x))`?